# How does CartoDB do international geocoding?

Tags: carto, geocoding

I work on projects overseas so I wanted to see how it does international geocoding -- can or does it use addresses, town names, neighborhood names, or what? And what areas does that cover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two options for the geocoder. You can map addresses using the high precision geocoder ("By addresses" option) or you can use the other ones if you're going to map "common" data, like Countries, Counties, States, City names, or other administrative regions. We also cover areas for zipcodes in Canada, USA, France, Australia, Spain...

We're working everyday to improve the internal geocoder adding new city names, new administrative regions. Besides the geocoder, we have a common-data section where we're adding useful datasets (as Congressional Districts in the USA) that may be interesting for you. You can check this section clicking on the Common Data link in the top-right corner of your dashboard.

Hope this helps. If you need specific coverage information about some country, just let us know and we will give you further details about or geocoder status regarding that country.